# Unbale to build shared library of go code which is having import "C" on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, go, gcc, cl

I have a go file (print.go):

```
import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

//export SumPrint
func SumPrint(a, b int) C.int {
    fmt.Println("Sum printed form GO code = ", a+b)
    return C.int(a + b)
}
func main() {}
```

and C++ file (main.cpp), which will use the method SumPrint.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libprinter.h"

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "Sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is : " << SumPrint(a, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

When generating .dll file from go code it is giving error:

```
E:\Test> go build -buildmode=c-shared -o libprinter.dll print.go
go: no Go source files
```

I installed mingw gcc compiler and added the path in ENV, then it is building perfectly.
But the issue is the library im not able to use in Visual Studio to build the C++ code (which is using cl compiler).
[image]
So, I want to generate the go library with cl compiler so that I can use it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you want to compile a package main into a dll?

Comment: I want to call go method from Cpp code to perform some job. When I build Cpp code using g++ from command line, it is working. Since VS uses cl compiler, it is not able to  read .dll file generated by Mingw compiler.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and if your IDE is giving trouble: Use a different one or none.

Comment: is there any option, we can change the GCC compiler used by the go build command to use cl compiler?

Comment: Like everybody go use CC as the C compiler, to spell it out `CC=cl go build` if cl is your C compiler.

Comment: I tried to set the CC to cl ```go env -w "CC=cl" ``` but the issue is still same ```go: no Go source files```